# Adding objects to array, array returning null

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have 2 arrays that receive information from a database. One, called json, contains posts with user id's and the other, called userJson, contains all the users with their id's. If the the user id from json  equals a user id from userJson, I would like to populate a 3rd array with that users username. I am using the following code:

```
NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *userInfo = [userArray objectAtIndex:0];
for (int i=0; i<[json count]; i++) {
    if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"user_id"] isEqualToString:[info objectForKey:@"user_id"]]) {
        [usernameArray addObject:[userInfo objectForKey:@"username"]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", usernameArray);
```

usernameArray is the 3rd array that should contain the usernames. When I print it, it prints out null various times.

Comment: My first question is, do you have this line of code? usernameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: No I do not. @Ryan Tobin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first add this:

```
usernameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Then change your loop to the following:

```
NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *userInfo;
for (int i=0; i<[userArray count]; i++) {
    userInfo = [userArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([[userInfo objectForKey:@"user_id"] isEqualToString:[info objectForKey:@"user_id"]]) {
        [usernameArray addObject:[userInfo objectForKey:@"username"]];
    }
}
```